# What's the benefit of version.rb in Ruby gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

It is common to have a version.rb file, defining the version of the gem, like:

```
module Foo
  VERSION = "0.0.1"
end
```

and in the .gemspec file, require the version.rb and use Foo::VERSION there.

What is the benefit of this convention?

--

Also, sometime when namespace is used, the generated verison file can be deeply in nested folders. Wouldn't it be easier to place a version.rb directly under lib/ and specifying the version there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what gem builder you used. Having a separate file makes it easy to stomp and rebuild as you bump version numbers with `rake` tasks, for example. this is a lot easier than fiddling with a source file and trying not to damage anything.

Some packagers use a separate `VERSION` file.

Answer (score 4):

This is done this way to reduce churn (change rate) on .gemspec file. I imagine that dependency changes are much more important than version bumps (which are also more frequent). So version changes would add too much noise and hide important commits.

Comment: Why care about the gemspec's change rate? Just to keep its git history cleaner? It doesn't seem important to me. I think a better reason is that many gems, at some point, want to read the version from some application code. E.g., `rake --version` references `Rake::VERSION`.

Comment: @DanielLubarov:  Clean commit history is not important to you? Oh my. Your suggestion is a good guess too, but git history is quite important. That's why we squash feature branches into one or few commits.

Comment: Personally I would never add indirection to my code just for the purpose of shortening a file's git log. Polished code is more important than polished git history, for me anyway.

Comment: So true, that's why I always put `name.rb` and `author.rb` to reduce change rate since gem name and author are rarely chaged.

Answer (score 3):

In short, if your gem doesn't need to know the current version itself, then you don't need a `version.rb`. Even some of the well-known gems like `rack` don't use it.

Let's say you are building an executable gem that contains an option `-v` to see the current version, or you have to print current version to warn developers there are some deprecated changes, then to `require` a separated version file is much more convenient and efficient than parse the gemspec.

It's just a convention in Ruby community. The main reason of why `version.rb` is everywhere is that lots of gems are built by `bundler gem`.